# Elasticsearch reverse match_phrase

Tags: elasticsearch

Consider following document:

```
{
  "Title": "Western Europe"
}
```

I'd like to run such search queries against *Title* field

- *Apple in Western Europe*
- *Apple in Eastern Europe*

I could run a simple match query:

```
POST /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "Title": "Apple in Western Europe"
    }
  }
}
```

It obiviously would match and bring it back irregardless of which search phrase I'd use. But I'd like to make a query that would bring my document back only if *Title* field *phrase matches* my search query. Is that possible? Are there any additional parameters? It seems like a reverse case for [phrase matching](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html).

If not, should I consider reindexing my data with shingles?

So in this scenario running this (with additional parameters) wouldn't score and bring back my document.

```
POST /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "Title": "Apple in Eastern Europe"
    }
  }
}
```

**tl;dr**

How do I write a query that would bring back document if all of its field (the one I'm searching on) tokens are present in my search query?
For instance my field in document contains these two tokens only:

- abc
- xyz

And if my search phrase is, for instance *Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit **abc xyz***, document is **brought back**.

If it's *Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit **xyz***, it's **not brought back**.

Comment: `"bring my document back only if Title field phrase matches my search query"` your search query is `Apple in Western Europe`. Maybe you wanted to say "what's after `in` should match `title`"?

Comment: In this very specific case yes.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I've updated my question with **tl;dr**. I hope that makes it clear.

Comment: The order of the terms matters?

Comment: That's a good question. No, it doesn't.

Comment: I think the only option is using scripts. But if you are doing this then you don't actually use Elasticsearch.

Comment: True, I was interested if it can be done in Elasticsearch only. Thank you.

Comment: I think it can be done with shingles, but the order part is tricky

Comment: As index analyzer you'd use a `lowercase`d `keyword` analyzer. And as search analyzer you'd use a `shingle` token filter. Then, when searching, a document will match if one of combined shingles matches the single term in the document.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Percolator Query ([ES Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html)):

1. Index the queries you would like to match with
2. Compatible with metadata associated with the queries
3. Send a document in the search request
4. Get the queries that match

## Example for your use case

### Create the mapping

- `query`: Accept an ES query with all the power behind
- `Title`: A metadata (optional)

```
PUT /my_index
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "Title": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "query": {
                "type": "percolator"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Add a document

```
PUT /my_index/_doc/1
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "Title": "Western Europe"
    }
  },
  "Title": "Western Europe"
}
```

### Get the matched query

```
POST /my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "percolate": {
            "field": "query",
            "document": {
                "Title": "Apple in Western Europe"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know Stefan has given a simple and efficient solution in the comments, but you may also want to look at [Span Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/span-queries.html) as an FYI!!

I've created sample mapping, documents, query and response:

### Mapping:

```
PUT my_span_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Title":{
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Documents:

```
POST my_span_index/_doc/1
{
  "Title": "Western Europe"
}

POST my_span_index/_doc/2
{
  "Title": "Eastern Europe"
}

//slop - distance between words Western and Europe here is 13
POST my_span_index/_doc/3
{
  "Title": "As far as Western culture is America, we see gradually more and more of the same in Europe"
}
```

### Span Query:

```
POST my_span_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "span_near" : {
            "clauses" : [
                { "span_term" : { "Title": "western" } },
                { "span_term" : { "Title": "europe" } }
            ],
            "slop" : 12,                                <---- Distance Between Words
            "in_order" : true                           <---- If order is important
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I made use of [Span Near](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-near-query.html) & [Span Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-term-query.html) and do note the comments above.

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.5420371,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_span_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.5420371,
        "_source" : {
          "Title" : "Western Europe"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_span_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 0.028773852,
        "_source" : {
          "Title" : "As far as Western culture is America, we see gradually more and more of the same in Europe"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that in the response the doc having `id:3` is also returned, however if you change the slop to lesser value, it would not appear.

The pain would be that you'd end up writing/generating long query at your application side if your request is going to have more tokens.

Hope I helped!!

Answer (score 0):

Try with "Intervals query"with different different parameter that could help you.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-intervals-query.html

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should provide more help than just a link or otherwise your answer will get flagged as link-only answer and eventually be deleted.