# Elastic Search: find document by analyzed field only if all words from field are contained in query

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search

Let's consider following case - I have list of some video titles and video categories which are indexed in elastic.

And task is to match video with categories.

I have three categories in the index:

```
{
  "category" : "rock climbing"
  ...
},

{
  "category" : "rock and roll"
  ...
}
```

And

```
{
  "category" : "outdoor"
  ...
}
```

`"category"` field is mapped to analyzed string and uses multiple analyzers.
So inverted index for first document is `"rock, climb"`, second -  `"outdoor"` and for the last one is `"rock, roll"`.

Now I want to find all available categories to video with title `"outdoor rock climbing in national park"`

So I need to receive `"rock climbing"` and `"outdoor"`

I am trying to run following query

```
{
 "query": {
   "match": {
     "category": "outdoor rock climbing in national park"
   }
 }
}
```

And it returns all documents, because it founds documents by occurrences of `"outdoor, rock and climb"`.

But I want query to return only those documents where query contains all inverted index words.

Analyzed query: `outdoor`,`rock`,`climb`,`nation`,`park`

Expected result: `outdoor`, `rock+climb`

I am beginner in the elastic search, please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580295/elasticsearch-match-all-words-from-document-in-the-search-query

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32779023/elasticsearch-reverse-match-phrase